# Django installed apps error

Tags: django, python-2.7

Totally new to Django trying to work through their tutorial I got to  and am getting this error:

```
 RuntimeError: Model class polls.models.Question doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.
```

I went through and all the different files look correct. I dont want to post them all because that would make the question hard to read so if you need to see something comment and I will add it.

I've checked all the steps twice but I hit a wall any ideas?

Comment: As the error message suggests, you need to have poll in INSTALLED_APPS of settings.py

Comment: where is that supposed to go? I havent seen anything like that yet?

Comment: So is it sorted out?

Comment: Yes, I am going to redo the entire tut from the beginning. Thanks guys, this is my first foray into web programming

Comment: although it's tempting to start fresh, finding these problems and fixing them is helpful cos you get a better understanding of how things work.

Comment: Yeah, I want a working model to play off of like a fully functional known good install. Then I can start tinkering. I dont really learn by reading I learn by interacting with the code.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue in part 5 when testing the app. Before this it worked fine.

I actually resolved it by removing __init__.py from the same directory as manage.py

Answer (score 0):

You're missing this step:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial02/#s-activating-models

"Edit the mysite/settings.py file again, and change the INSTALLED_APPS setting to include the string 'polls.apps.PollsConfig'"